# increasing the rank of a matrix with rank-1 updates

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a following problem that I am stuck on and not sure how to proceed. Any suggestions are really appreciated.

Given a non-square $m \times n$ matrix $A = [M | I ],$ I order the columns of $A$ with COLAMD and pick the first $m$ columns from the COLAMD ordering to form a basis $m\times m$ matrix $B$.

Often it happens that the $rank(B) < m,$ and I'd like to repair the basis matrix $B$ by replacing the columns of $B$ with columns from $I$ that is part of $A$. When doing so I'd like to replace the minimum number of columns of B to preserve most of the COLAMD ordering to preserve the fill-in reducing properties.

I tried the obvious and computed the null space of B and used the resulting vectors to find out linearly dependent columns and replaced them one by one with columns from the standard basis. However, very often it leads to $B = I$ which is not what I want.

Is there a good and relatively easy to implement method for approaching this kind of problem?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Is $I$ the identity matrix? And what is a "basis $m\times m$ matrix"?

Comment: Yes, the $I$ is an identity matrix. The basis matrix B is an $m \times m$ matrix with $m$ linearly independent columns.

Comment: But then the rank of $B$ is $m$, right?

Comment: Yes, that’s the end state where I would like to end up. I should probably clarify that I’d like to modify a rank deficient matrix B to obtain an m-dimensional basis of full rank m. The problem I’m trying to figure out is which linearly dependent vectors from B to replace with vectors from I to end up with a full rank B and perform the least amount of rank-1 updates.

Comment: Have you tried a QR factorization of the matrix $A$? Try it with and without reordering. If necessary, do a QR factorization with column pivoting. If you have no luck here, then consider this [site](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/). You can ask the moderator to move migrate the question you.